# Block default chrome Downloader

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

I'm writing a download manager app for Linux so I use a chrome extension to add listener to all download links in page and and when a download link clicked link send to a native app. everything is ok but I want to prevent show default chrome save dialog when download links clicked . how? thank you.

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561969/how-to-download-files-automatically

Answer (score 0):

A quite limited approach to intercept single-clicked links would be to inject a content script with:

```js
window.addEventListener("mousedown", interceptFunction); // intercept mouseclicks
window.addEventListener("keydown", interceptFunction); // intercept Enter key on a link
```

The interceptFunction would check if the link is likely to be a downloadable file judging by the url (file extension) and cancel the event:

```js
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Then it would send the url to your background page which will tell your native app to start the download.

To make the decision whether to download or not more reliable you may perform a XMLHttpRequest with `method: "HEAD"` and analyze the response headers (you'll have to deal with CORS though) like `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>` and others.

Comment: Isn't it better to hook into `chrome.downloads.onCreated`?